# Not very sure about this contraposition...open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, logic

I have this lemma that states,

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Then, $A$ is open in $X$ if and only if $\forall x \in A$, there is a neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $A$.

Now, I am looking at a particular problem that tries to prove that some $A$ is closed. It says, in the solution,

> By lemma 1(the above lemma), it is enough to prove that each point of $X$ not in $A$ has a neighborhood that does not meet $A$.

I am assuming this is what is known as the contrapositive of the lemma. I wikipedia'd it to make sure I understand this;

> Contrapositive: $P \Rightarrow Q$ then $\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P$

Well, in this case it's "$\Leftrightarrow$"  so I guess it can go both ways. Anyway, my concern is...

The contrapositive of the lemma, to me, would be

> $A$ is not open in $X$ if and only if $\forall x \not\in A$ there is a neighborhood of $x$ that does not meet $A$.

It's close to what the solution is saying, however, "not open in $X$" does not necessarily mean "closed" no? In the world of math BOTH open and closed and NEITHER opened or closed, can happen, right?

If that's the case, why can I use this lemma to prove a subspace being closed? Am I wrong with the concept of contrapositive? Or closed/open? Help please

Comment: $A$ is closed if $X-A$ is open and $X-A$ is open if for any point in $X-A$ (so for every point outside $A$) there exists a neighborhood of that point which is contained in $X-A$ (so which does not touch $A$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the contrapositive : it's the lemma applied to the complement of $A$.

Let's put $U = X\setminus A$. Then $A$ is closed iff $U$ is open, so by the lemma $A$ is closed iff for every point $x\in U$ there is a neighbourhood of $x$ included in $U$. This means that for every point not in $A$, there is a neighbourhood not meeting $A$.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that what is happening is that prove that the set A is closed is the same that prove that the set $A^c=X$\ $A$ is open.